# navbar css is not loading while using twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap css framework. I have installed a local copy in /js folder of my application.

I have a piece of code in my home.php file:

```
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Basically, it loads the css well, the span5 division works. But the nav bar does not seem to be appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to also include the basic bootstrap.css file on the page as well as the bootstrap-responsive.css file.

See this example:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html